# How to listen the event DOCUMENT_COMPLETE in Firefox with Kango framework?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, firefox-addon

I'm trying to execute an action when page finish loading using the [Kango framework](http://kangoextensions.com/). It works in Google Chrome, but don't work in Mozilla Firefox:

**extension_info.json:**

```
{
"content_scripts": ["content_script.js"], 
"description": "Extension description", 
"creator": "Kango", 
"background_scripts": [
    "main.js"
], 
"homepage_url": "http://kangoextensions.com/", 
"version": "0.9.0", 
"browser_button": {
    "caption": "Kango", 
    "icon": "icons/button.png", 
    "tooltipText": "Kango"
}, 
"name": "MyExtension"
}
```

**content_script.js**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name MyExtension
// @include http://*
// @include https://*
// ==/UserScript==
```

**main.js:**

```
function MyExtension() {
var self = this;

kango.ui.browserButton.addEventListener(kango.ui.browserButton.event.COMMAND, function() {
    self._onCommandClick();
});

kango.browser.addEventListener(kango.browser.event.DOCUMENT_COMPLETE, function(event) {
    alert('On document complete!');
    kango.console.log(event);
});
}

MyExtension.prototype = {
    _onCommandClick: function() {
        kango.browser.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'});
    }
};

var extension = new MyExtension();
```

Can anybody explain why it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox, but works in Google Chrome?

I've tried other events like 'TAB_CHANGED' and 'BEFORE_NAVIGATE', but they also do not work in Mozilla Firefox.

Thanks! :)

[]'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem, but however the event is triggered

My background count consists of

main.js

```
var handleTabCreated = function (event){
   kango.console.log("Tab created directed to " + event.url);
   count++;
   requestTab = event.target;
  /*
   * Remove event listener
   */
   kango.browser.removeEventListener(kango.browser.event.DOCUMENT_COMPLETE  , handleTabCreated);
   result = requestTab.dispatchMessage('ParseData' , count);
   kango.console.log(result);   // Returns False and no message is sent to Tab
}    

kango.addMessageListener('Content2Background', function(event) {
   sourceTab = event.target;
   img = (event.data);
   kango.console.log('Received message from content ' + img);
   kango.browser.addEventListener(kango.browser.event.DOCUMENT_COMPLETE  , handleTabCreated)
   kango.browser.tabs.create({url:'www.pngine.com',focused:false});
}
```

and in my foreground script i only trigger the dispatch a message to trigger the code.

content.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name testitem
// @namespace content
// @include http://*
// @include https://*
// @require jquery-1.9.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.$.noConflict(true);
img = 'test';
kango.dispatchMessage('Content2Background', img );
```

This works in both Chrome and Firefox.
The only problem in firefox is that i cannot dispatch any methods to the newly created tab, however i am able to do so in Chrome.

and here is the rest of my project code

```
{
"name": "Test item",
"version": "1.2.0",
"description": "Test item demo",
"creator": "Ahmed",
"homepage_url": "http://pngine.com/",
"background_scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js","main.js"],
"content_scripts": ["content.js"],
"browser_button": {
    "caption": "Test_item_demo",
    "tooltipText": "Test_item_demo",
    "icon": "icons/button.png"
},
"context_menu_item": {
    "caption": "Blog Verifier"
}
}
```

I hope it helps you, and i'll try to check why i am not able to send msgs to the created tab.

Best of Luck